# Run _.filter and _.reject as a single operation, like Haskell's Data.List.Partition

Tags: underscore.js, filtering, lodash

I would like to partition values in a JavaScript array into two separate arrays based on whether a predicate returns `true` or `false` for the value. This can be easily done as two operations using Underscore or Lo-Dash:

```
var values = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var even = function (num) { return num % 2 === 0; };
var evens = _.filter(values, even);
var odds = _.reject(values, even);
```

This will run the predicate on each value twice, which is alright here but could be problematic if `values` were replaced with a larger set of data, and if `even` were replaced with a more computationally expensive predicate.

I looked through the documentation for Lo-Dash, but could not see anything that would do this in a single operation. I can manually write such a function, but it seems a strange omission. Is there a function like this that I am missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Underscore has [`_.partition`](http://underscorejs.org/#partition):

> **partition** `_.partition(array, predicate)`
>
> Split **array** into two arrays: one whose elements all satisfy **predicate** and one whose elements all do not satisfy **predicate**.

but it seems that Lo-Dash doesn't (yet) have it. You could use [`groupBy`](http://lodash.com/docs#groupBy) instead:

```
var partition = _.groupBy(values, function(num) { return num % 2 === 0 });
```

and then pull the two pieces out of the `partition` object yourself; that's still two steps I suppose but only pass through `values`. This will, of course, stringify the boolean keys but that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: So the lesson is to check underscore docs first, rather than believe that lodash has everything from underscore. I guess I should look at submitting a patch to lodash for this.

Comment: `_.partition` is fairly new in Underscore, the [Change Log](http://underscorejs.org/#changelog) says it came in with 1.6.0 in February so maybe Lo-Dash hasn't gotten around to matching that part of the Underscore interface yet. I like the idea of submitting a patch.

Comment: Looks like partition is on its way into Lo-Dash, according to https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/177 (and they mention the same workaround of using `_.groupBy`),